# AVG Difference in Dates SSRS - Oracle Datasource CASE Statement

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2012

I have a query that works fine in Oracle.  When the query is used in a report within SSRS I get ....specified cast is not valid.  String from query below and an example of what has been tried follow it

Original Query

```
AVG(
  CASE 
    WHEN IDSTATUS = '1' 
      THEN (COLLECTED_DATE - START_DATE) 
    ELSE NULL 
  END
) AS "AVG COLLECTED TIME"
```

Attempted Fix

```
AVG(
  CASE 
    WHEN IDSTATUS = '1' 
      THEN TO_NUMBER((COLLECTED_DATE - START_DATE)) 
    ELSE NULL 
  END
) AS "AVG COLLECTED TIME"
```

Also tried

```
CAST(     
AVG(  
  CASE   
    WHEN IDSTATUS = '1'   
      THEN TO_NUMBER((COLLECTED_DATE - START_DATE))   
    ELSE NULL   
  END  
) AS NUMBER) AS "AVG COLLECTED TIME"
```

AND

```
AVG(CAST(  
  CASE   
    WHEN IDSTATUS = '1'   
      THEN TO_NUMBER((COLLECTED_DATE - START_DATE))   
    ELSE NULL   
  END AS NUMBER)  
) AS "AVG COLLECTED TIME"
```

Comment: I'll add that MIN and MAX of the same query return correct values

Comment: Having a query that works in the DB, but not SSRS is rather strange (in this context). Are you sure that the error is coming from the DB, and now how SSRS is trying to handle the returned type?

Comment: I believe the error is coming from SSRS handling of it and trying to figure out how to get around it.   Guessing it is looking at the number of days returned from the dates being subtracted as a date and not number but can't seem to figure out how to correct that

Comment: Can you copy and paste, or put up a screenshot of the actual error?

Comment: Warning  [rsErrorReadingDataSetField] The dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a definition for the Field ‘AVG COLLECTED TIME’. The data extension returned an error during reading the field. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataReaderWrapper.GetValue(Int32 fieldIndex)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.MappingDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 aliasIndex)

Comment: And how are you using this field? Do you have an expression, or format set that defines this as a Decimal somewhere? I'm curious what would happen if you put this in a table to just spit out raw data.

Comment: I've tried a handful of things.  Default (no formatting), Number, etc.